# Make a b-form-select with options after select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `b-form-select` with options that are available after the user selects some other inputs. I want to execute a function when they choose one of my dynamically `<b-form-option>` but i cannot get the value and the text.

Here is my code

```
<b-form-select
@change="priceNameSelected(group_xreoshs);
getListOfGroups(value, hmera_paralabhs, selectedDate_2);"
id="input-xora"
v-model="group_xreoshs"
class="mb-3"
>
<b-form-select-option :value="null">Επιλέξτε Group Χρέωσης</b-form-select-option>
<b-form-select-option
v-show="this.form.omada_dosame != null"
:value="`${this.form.omada_dosame }`"
:text="`${ this.omada_dosame_title }`"
>
</b-form-select-option>
<b-form-select-option
 v-show="this.form.omada_zhthse != null"
 :value="`${this.form.omada_zhthse }`"
 :text="`${ this.omada_zhthse_title }`"
 >
</b-form-select-option>
</b-form-select>
```

Comment: remove `this.` from template

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
<b-form-select v-model="group_xreoshs">
<b-form-select-option :value="this.form.omada_dosame">
{{ this.omada_dosame_title }}
</b-form-select-option>
<b-form-select-option :value="this.form.omada_zhthse">
{{ this.omada_zhthse }}
 </b-form-select-option>
</b-form-select>
```